AWS Cognito - Get a code after entering Coginto username and password using authorization endpoint
I have cognito user pool defined. When I run my app, it shows a custom login page (not hostedUI page), when I enter username and password, I want to get a code after clicking on signin button.
Using Cognito HostedUI page, when I enter username and password and click on signin button, it sends a code back (can be seen in browser's URL). I want to implement the same in my custom login page.

is it possible ?

If yes, how can I get a code when I enter username and password in my custom login page after clicking the signin button ?


I was just reading about authorization endpoint and tried below thing. I don't know if it is right
When signin button is clicked I make a GET call as below,
const requestOptions = {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"  
     }    
};


  fetch(`https://${process.env.domain}/oauth2/authorize?
  response_type=${process.env.responseType}&
  client_id=${process.env.appClientId}&
  redirect_uri=${process.env.redirectSignIn}&
  scope=openid+profile+aws.cognito.signin.user.admin`, requestOptions);

but it doesn't do anything.

Also, How and where to use entered username and password in above URL or anywhere else?

FYI I do have SSO login functionality and I'm able to get a code for SAML (Azure-ad) login but for cognito username and password I don't know how to get it.
